# How add padding-top to an ancre link?

Tags: html, css

I would like add a `padding-top` to my `div` when I click on the link to the anchor :

```
<a href="#myAnchor">Go to my anchor</a>

...

<div id="myAnchor"> ... </div>
```

The issues is that I want add the padding just when my link redirect me to the anchor. I don't want add `padding-top` in the html, I just don't want that my div is on the top of my page, I need a padding or margin top.

Thank you.

Comment: Add it with JavaScript?

Comment: You want to click on the link, and to have the padding applied *to the `div`*, or *to the `a`*, element?

Comment: yes it is that. In fact I don't want a padding in my html, I just need to translate all the page to the bottom (that mean add a "padding-top" between the top and my anchor Id)

Answer (score 11):

I think what you're trying to do is cause the link, when clicked, to scroll the browser window to a few pixels above the target, instead of having the target flush with the top of the browser window.

You can check this article for several solutions http://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/

The simplest solution, generally would appear to be to add in your css:

```
#myanchor{
  margin-top: -200px;
  padding-top: 200px;
}
```

Replacing 200px with whatever value you feel is appropriate.
You may also wish to use a class to apply this, as I asume you won't just wish to use it on the one item :)

Answer (score 1):

There's only one way I know of: javascript. If you're already using jquery:

```
 $('a[href="#myAncre"]').click(function(){
   $("#myAncre").css("padding-top", "20px");
   });
```

Although if you don't use jquery already, it might be worth to do it with simple javascript.

Comment: If I do like this that mean, if I scroll up there will have a blank of 20px. I don't want this.

Comment: I'm sorry, my magic powers failed me and didn't let me see that you didn't want that. Can you explain the behaviour you actually want by editing your original question, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think, best way is

```
#myanchor:before {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    height: 50px;
    margin: -50px 0 0;
}
```

Source and demo: *http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/demo/#method-B*

If you choose ugly way (that is `margin-top: -50px;` and `padding-top: 50px;`) layer will remain on the bottom and you need to use `z-index`.

Comment: I agree that the margin + padding way is ugly. Unfortunately, your way does nothing for me, the pointed to element still pushes against the top of the window.